# Concurrent threads, processes and multiple cores

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand the usage of CPU cores with regard to concurrent threads and processes. Please see the below questions:

1. Assume I have 2 CPU cores. When there are 2 processes running, each process has only 1 thread. Are the two processes using the 2 cores?
2. Assume I have 2 CPU cores. When there is 1 process running, which has 2 threads. Are the two threads using the 2 cores?
3. Assume I have 2 CPU cores. When there are 2 processes running, each process has 2 threads. How are the two cores used by those processes and cores?
4. How to calculate the maximum real concurrent execution given CPU cores? What are other factor I should take into account?

Answer (score 0):

1,2:  Quite likely but not definitely.   A portion of the system software determines what runs where.  It would be unlikely to choose to keep a process or thread waiting for cpu attention when there is one that is otherwise *idle*, it isn't absolute.

Most processing involves some sort of transfer to and from a device, network, etc.. Typically this necessitates a period of inactivity waiting for the transfer to complete.  During this inactivity, another process / thread can run on that cpu.  So, if a given process is 30% cpu time and 70% I/O time, then I can run about 3 of them concurrently on a single cpu without degrading performance.

3,4: Like the paragraph above implies, depending upon the workload, their could be any distribution of the threads among the cpus.  If the threads were all compute bound (100% cpu), most operating systems switch between them at a small enough granularity that all remain lively, and large enough that the switching has a minimal impact on them.

This *scheduling* may take other notions into consideration, such as data affinity.  Recently touched bits of data are likely to remain in the cpu cache when a thread has relinquished it.   The next time the thread is to be scheduled, it would be best to put it onto that cpu, to retain the effort required to warm the cache for it.  It might also think that two threads of one process (address space) are more likely to share data, so should prefer the same cpu.

4: depending upon your system, there are likely to be many performance analysis tools available.  Top, on UNIX-inspired systems is a simple tool which gives system wide utilization information, and the simple tool *time* will show how much time a process spent on a cpu vs real-world time.  If you run each of your tasks sequentially, noting the cpu-time that they take, then time them running concurrently, the ratio between these cpu-times indicates the scaling factor of your concurrent app.   Note that real-world time can be misleading because of io-overlap.